# Does method chaining in jQuery result in multiple loops i.e. one for each method

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I want to successively apply multiple methods over an array of jQuery objects, I could write something like

```
$('.myclass').css('width','10').addClass('foo')
```

Is this equivalent to

```
for(var i=0; i<$('.myclass').length); i++){
    $('.myclass').eq(i).css('width','10')
}
for(var i=0; i<$('.myclass').length); i++){
    $('.myclass').eq(i).addClass('foo')
}
```

**OR**

```
for(var i=0; i<$('.myclass').length); i++){
    $('.myclass').eq(i).css('width','10')
    $('.myclass').eq(i).addClass('foo')
}
```

i.e. if I have `n` methods chained, would that result in `n` different loops or would jQuery optimize the chain to apply all the methods in a single loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is equivalent to the 2 for-loops you have.

You can view it as,

1) find all elements, and store into 1 object.  So one object, but it contains all those elements.

2) loop through those elements, by changing their css, and return just the object as in (1)

3) loop through those elements again, by adding a class to them

because this is common in OOP, that you first have an object, and you invoke a method `css()` on it, and then after all is done, what `css()` returns (in jQuery, it typically returns the same object so that chaining works), now invoke `addClass()` to the object again.

**P.S.** You can pretty much simulate the same mechanism if you look at http://jsfiddle.net/T4wKm/5/

**P.P.S.** jQuery will not optimize it for you to make it into one loop, but in general, having one loop and doing multiple things vs having multiple loops to do one thing each, is not viewed as much difference in performance.  If you learn about `O()` (big O notation) later, you will know they all boil down to `O(n)`, and it is not much of a concern for computational speed if they are all `O(n)`.

Comment: Could you cite a source or explain how did you infer this? This is something that could be optimized inside jQuery, I suppose.

Comment: because this is a typical, common pattern in object oriented programming, where you have an object, and invoke a method on it, and get back something, and then you can yet invoke another method on it

Comment: You are right. I verified this by stepping through the code in a debugger. It indeed executes the first method for all elements and then goes on to the next method. Does this mean, if I have lots of elements & lots of methods to be chained, I should not use jQuery if I care about performance? Or can this be done in a better way in jQuery?

Comment: Please see the P.S. added to the answer.  Typically, I never heard of developers worry about chaining multiple times.  Even if there are hundreds of elements you are talking about, and multiple loops applied, with the computer and the faster JS interpreter nowadays, developers in general don't worry too much about it.

Comment: However, there is something such as, when there are thousands of rows in your table, and you want to bind a handler to each row, you can be binding thousands of handlers, and in general, developers may use what is called event delegation to bind one handler on the table, and find the row the user clicked on

Comment: Thanks for the explanation & the example. This is a good suggestion.

Comment: By the way, you can also change the class of the container from "foo" to "bar", and make all elements inside the container look different just by the various CSS styles you have defined (usually in the .css file)